# how to track source of current project in team foundation server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs

I got some source code in java/eclipse which had run currently from local machine which was taken some time before from third party server.
Now if I want to track that this project is taken from which folder or path of that TFS how could I get? Because there are lots of similar kind of project copies available on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TFS Everywhere to see the status of TFS from Eclipse:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs.aspx

Comment: hay,thanx for reply, but I don't want to check status, I just want to see the exact location from where my project was broughtup...and when I track it, I t shows just $/ class hierarchy and not server location

Comment: Its been a while since I used Eclipse/TFSE.  Doesn't Eclipse tell you where your files are located?

Answer (score 0):

Your project/solution has been mapped to your local machine when you working on it. All operations are handled on your local machine, after you do check-in, these changes will be added to your TFS. $/ actually means server location. You should have mapped a local path to the server path when you working on your project/solution.

You may check more information about how to share your project in Eclipse at website below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568708(v=vs.120).aspx